# Fido U2F client side javascript source code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-app-engine, fido-u2f, yubico

I'm looking for a JavaScript source code (client side) to make communication between Fido U2F token and Google Chrome (Version 41.0.2272.89 m).

Please help me

Comment: I don't think there is "a Javascript sourcecode". Because Javascript is implemented into web browsers using standards. Each web browser has its own way of implementing these standards. Are you looking for Javascript interpreter ?

Comment: I assume you want to authenticate with Fido U2F? So would you like browse to your distributed server application and authenticate with a USB hardware token, that e.g. reads the fingerprint?

Comment: I'm trying to run this JavaScript function :window.u2f.register(), then I'll show the token  RegisterResponse data in an alert before I'll send it to my server. that's what I wanna do

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use FIDO U2F to allow users to authenticate with my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637660/how-do-i-use-fido-u2f-to-allow-users-to-authenticate-with-my-website)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example to getting the Token response for registration using Yubico u2f-api file

```
var RegistrationData = {"challenge":"dG7vN-E440ZnJaKQ7Ynq8AemLHziJfKrBpIBi5OET_0",
                     "appId":"https://localhost:8443",
                     "version":"U2F_V2"};

window.u2f.register([RegistrationData], [],
  function(data) {if(data.errorCode) {
        alert("U2F failed with error: " + data.errorCode);
        return;
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

you've to include the u2f-api.js and use an Https server

Comment: How to include `u2f-api.js` and where is the `u2f-api.js` file (that I can download) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the registration, and even parse the registrationData using Javascript

```
let registerRequest = {
 challenge: 'RegisterChallenge',
 version: 'U2F_V2'
}
u2f.register('https://localhost', [registerRequest], [],
 (response) => {
 U2FRegistration.parse(response.registrationData);
 console.log(U2FRegistration);
 }
);
```

Here is a github repo demonstrating this: https://github.com/infiniteloopltd/U2FJS - and as mentioned, you need a HTTPS server, and include u2f-api.js

Comment: How to include `u2f-api.js` and where is the `u2f-api.js` file (that I can download) ?

Comment: @CHOOYJ - You can download it from here: https://www.u2fapi.com/