# How to get key from Yubico device

Tags: yubico

I did not found library for getting key on https://developers.yubico.com/.
Does anybody know how to get one time key from Yubico after pressing button there?

Answer (score 1):

This is the library you need: https://demo.yubico.com/js/u2f-api.js

This very nice SO answer tells you how to use the library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640348/451893